# Message template should be compile time constant

Tags: c#, .net-core, rider

I have this code

```
[HttpGet("average/{videoGuid}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AverageRatingOfVideo([FromRoute] string videoGuid)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Finding average rating of video : {videoGuid}");
    var avg = await _ratingService.GetVideoRatingAverageAsync(videoGuid);
    return Ok(avg);
}
```

and I'm getting a warning here `$"Finding average rating of video : {videoGuid}"`

> Message template should be compile time constant

I'm using **Rider**, there is no suggestion to fix this warning.

I can't understand why this gives me a warning, how could I fix this ?

Comment: No, I don't think so, my problem related to `c#`

Comment: Try to extract this $"Finding average rating of video : {videoGuid}" to some variable, like var  msg = $"Finding average rating of video : {videoGuid}"; and use this message as LogInformation argument

Comment: @godot tried that but the warning still exist

Comment: It is a feature of Serilog, see discussion [here](https://gitter.im/serilog/serilog?at=5d81e159a38dae3a6371ae37).

Comment: try `_logger.LogInformation("Finding average rating of video : {videoGuid}", videoGuid)` or `_logger.LogInformation("Finding average rating of video : " + videoGuid)`. I would say that the reason for it is structured logging which uses the same curly brackets for templating and analyzer missing the interpolated string part.

Comment: If you use serilog - check out [this post](https://nblumhardt.com/2015/01/c-6-string-interpolation-and-serilog/)

Comment: Report to JetBrains as a bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER and you might get an answer there.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

The way to get rid of the warning is to supply the variable videoGuid separately, like this:

```
_logger.LogInformation("Finding average rating of video : {VideoGuid}", videoGuid);
```

Here, I first removed the $ sign, thereby turning off the string interpolation performed by C#. The `{videoGuid}` in the string now becomes a "property" instead, and so I pass the variable as a second argument to LogInformation. Rider also complains that properties in strings should start with a capital letter, so I changed it to `{VideoGuid}`.

Now for the real question: *Why* is there a warning?

The answer is that string interpolation prevents structured logging. When you pass the variables after the message, you make it possible for the logger to save them separately. If you just save the log to a file you may not see a difference, but if you later decide to log to a database or in some JSON format, you can just change your logging sink and you will be able to search through the logs much easier without changing all the log statements in your code.

There's a good discussion of this over on [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/312197/benefits-of-structured-logging-vs-basic-logging).

Comment: This is a feature of Serilog right? Are you using it or did they introduce structured logging in .net 5? It might be good to clarify in any case.

Comment: Yamaç Kurtuluş, I'm using [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/), at least for the moment. I'm guessing the IntelliJ team keeps a list of frameworks supporting structured logging somewhere to know when to activate this warning (or maybe they have a more sophisticated algorithm – there must be a _lot_ of effort and code behind many of the warnings that their tools generate).

Comment: for me the solution (which Rider/MS/C# creators offer?) does not make sense, it may mislead code since the named arguments are just ordered arguments - no name match, so the code `logger.LogDebug("hey {Foo}, hi {Bar}", bar, foo);` will log `hey bar, hi foo`, even more renaming variables `bar` and `foo` will make code strange `...("hey {Foo}, hi {Bar}", big, bang);` - Rider/ReSharper does not support rename in {} as well atm.

Comment: @svonidze the usage of `{}` in the string can simply be seen as the same as what you would use for `string.Format()`. You're able to add named variables to make it easier to read but you could just as well do `logger.LogDebug("hey {0}, hi {1}", bar, foo)` - it will be the same. Keep that in mind, it might help you.

Comment: @NewteqDeveloper it is clear, that is what I meant under "the named arguments are just ordered arguments - no name match", it does not replace beauty and clearness of string interpolation

Comment: Oh yes, I understand. I agree with you – it does not replace the clearness that string interpolation does, however, as the answerer mentioned, it helps a ton with structured logging. If you’re only ever going to write logs in a string format to a text file, I would say that you can completely ignore this warning. After all, it’s just a warning. But, to allow the structured logging, it will help to fix the warning as mentioned.

Comment: @svonidze It is absolutely critical, if you're a library developer, that you do not ignore this warning, because you will flood downstream logging systems with messages that can't be properly elided or compressed. Whether or not is is "cleaner" isn't relevant in this case, because non-constant templates are wrong when using a structured logging framework.

Comment: Does it work with something like `Logger.LogInformation("Server state is {Server.State}.", Server.State);`? I hope it does, because I've changed a lot of lines like this ;) Compiler doesn't complain, I wonder if the strings will be interpolated correctly in the log.

Comment: @EKW "elided"??

Comment: @thargenediad https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elide

Comment: @Harry I'd try to avoid punctuation in variables (and messages, really). No guarantee that the log target will support that. If you're using Seq, I'm not sure if it is unsupported, but you'd likely eventually end up with a query like `select * from stream where Server.State = 'foo' and 'Server.State' = 'bar'`

Comment: I had a log like this `_logger.LogInformation(
                                    $"Processing notifications for client {client.CompanyName} and user {user.UserId}");` but while debugging this is what it showed `Processing notifications for client {client.CompanyName} and user {user.UserId}`. It didn't care about replacing the correct values.